# Java compute duration of Project and Tasks doesnt work

Tags: java, date, datediff, duration, java.util.date

I am trying to compute the duration Of each Project and each Task appointed to the Project, unfortunately it always returns 0.
**computeDuration**:

```
        Date minDate = projectTasks[0].gettaskFromDate();
        Date maxDate = projectTasks[0].gettaskEndDate();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; ++i) {
            if (projectTasks[i] != null && projectTasks[i].gettaskEndDate() != null && projectTasks[i].gettaskFromDate() != null) {
                projectTasks[i].settaskDuration(utils.Globals.computeDuration(projectTasks[i].gettaskFromDate(), projectTasks[i].gettaskEndDate()));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; ++i) {
            if (projectTasks[i] != null && projectTasks[i].gettaskEndDate() != null && projectTasks[i].gettaskFromDate() != null) {
                if (utils.Globals.validateDates(projectTasks[i].gettaskFromDate(), minDate)) {
                    minDate = projectTasks[i].gettaskFromDate();
                }
                if (utils.Globals.validateDates(maxDate, projectTasks[i].gettaskEndDate())) {
                    maxDate = projectTasks[i].gettaskEndDate();
                }
            }
        }
        setprojectDuration(utils.Globals.computeDuration(minDate, maxDate));
    }
```

**utils.Globals.validateDates**:

```
public static boolean validateDates(Date from, Date to){
        return from.before(to);
    }
```

**utils.Globals.computeDuration**:

```
 public static int computeDuration(Date from, Date to){
        long diffIn = Math.abs(to.getTime() - from.getTime());
        int duration = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffIn, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return duration;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete `Date` class and not `LocalDate`?  Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE, compile, and run hundreds of tests to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: Its for a project for my uni and I am obliged to use the Date  format.I am well aware that LocalDate is far more useful. Also, my project uses 7 classes with each one intertwined so im having a rough time creating a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @dannyph Could you please nofify your tutor that they're using an obsolete class that was supplanted a decade ago?

Comment: Please provide an example of Date arguments which you believe should produce a duration greater than zero days, but which are instead causing zero to be returned.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I run `int diff = computeDuration(Date.from(Instant.parse("2023-04-01T12:00:00Z")), Date.from(Instant.parse("2023-04-08T12:00:00Z")));`, I get 7 as expected.

Comment: And yes, teachers requiring their students to use `Date` in 2023 deserve to be sacked. It’s really nothing useful to teach.

Answer (score 0):

You could confirm if the diff between your from and to dates is over one day or not. If all diffs is less than one day, then **computeDuration** return 0 always.

Please check DAYS diff is expected or not in the blow codes.

```
 public static int computeDuration(Date from, Date to){
        long diffIn = Math.abs(to.getTime() - from.getTime());
        int duration = (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffIn, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return duration;
    }
```

Comment: I checked the given front end and i the difference between dates is always more than a day

Comment: Print out the from date, to dates and duration in computeDuration method. Then confirm if they are expected or not. I guess there is no magic here.

Comment: Here is a part of the print:
       0      EVENFLOW      490000.0    0       PENDING
   TaskID   Title    Start Date   End Date  Duration  Status

    0.1 Dynamic Maintenance of Neural Models 23/03/2023 01/11/2023 0 PENDING
    0.2 Formal Verification Models 01/04/2023 29/09/2023 0 COMPLETED

       1      CREXDATA      1800000.58    0       PENDING

Comment: I mean the parameters of method computeDuration.
Anyway, try 2 numOfTasks, debug or print the intermediate variables to verify the values.  BTW, Did you see any exception threw when you run your code?